# How do i reuse an authorization from QuickBooks oauth?

Tags: oauth, quickbooks-online

I'm implementing a website where users can signup/login with their quickbooks account.
I have done all the OAuth2 process, and I get the `realmId`, the `accessToken` and the `refreshToken`. Then I create a user identified by this `realmId`, and save tokens with it.
How do i reuse this credentials so user do not have to authorize my app again?
I always redirect the user to quickbooks oauth flow because user need to login in quickbooks so I can know who is he, but the authorize windows always appear too.
Is there a way to skip the "authorize" button click in the oauth flow?
What i'm missing?